# Handling File ownership issues in a PHP apache application

Tags: php, git, apache, ubuntu

Env: Linux

PHP apps runs as "www-data"

PHP files in /var/www/html/app owned by "ubuntu". Source files are pulled from git repository. /var/www/html/app is the local git repository (origin: bitbucket)

Issue: Our Developers and Devops would like to pull the latest sources (frequently), and would like to initiate this over the web (rather than putty -> and running the git pull command).

However, since the PHP files run as "www-data" it cannot run a git pull (as the files are owned by "ubuntu").

I am not comfortable with both alternatives:

- Running Apache server as "ubuntu", due to obvious security issue.
- The git repository files to be "www-data", as it makes it very inconvenient for developers logging into the server and editing the files directly.

What is the best practice for handling this situation? I am sure this must be a common issue for many setups.

Right now, we have a mechanism where the Devops triggers the git pull request from the web (where a PHP job - running as "www-data" creates a temp file). And a Cron job, running as "ubuntu", reads the temp file trigger and then issues the "git pull" command. There is a time lag, between the trigger and the actual git pull, which is a minor irritant now. I am in the process of setting up docker containers, and have the requirement to update the repo, running on multiple containers within the same host. I wanted to use this opportunity to solve this problem, in a better way, and looking for advise regarding this.

Comment: Can you solve this problem by using groups?

Comment: @Kvothe: Using groups is a good idea. Few points need to be explored: 1) File ownership of new files, as a result of git pull, would be www-data 2) May need to set umask (before git pull) making files group-writable 3) Should the developers set the file permissions, before adding new files and how this would work, when Windows users add.. Will check them

Comment: Add ubuntu user to www-data group, make webroot chgrp -R www-data and chmod g+s www-data so all new files are correctly owned. Aside: consider fabric for simple deployment issues like this. It will use SSH, but is as simple as 'fab webservers pull'.

Comment: Once I did it this way: I kep the ownership "www-data" and whenever I wanted a direct and quick (and dirty) file modification, I used to do it on bitbucket directly, and trigger the pull. You can use branches to separate things. Not a perfect solution, but worked for me.

Comment: @markdwhite: The SSH idea is a good one. I can go either that way, set group permissions or even consider suggestion from musa. Will update soon, on how I go about this.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Rocketeer](http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu) and groups to deploy. Rocketeer deploys with the user set to the deployment user (*ubuntu* in your case) and read/write permission for it, and the *www-data* group with read/execute permission. Then, as a last step, it modifies the permissions on the web-writable folders so that php can write to them.

Rocketeer executes over ssh, so can be triggered from anywhere, as long as it can connect to the server (public keys help). You might be able to setup your continuous integration/automated deployment to trigger a deploy automatically when a branch is updated/tests pass.

In any case, something where the files are owned by one user that can modify them and the web group can read the files should solve the main issue.

If you are planning on using docker, the simplest way would be to generate a new docker image for each build that you can distribute to your hosts. The docker build process would simply pull the latest changes on creation and never update itself. If a new version needs to be deployed, a new immutable image with the latest code is created and distributed.